# Two threads of FixedThreadPool are dead locked, Will thread pool create two more threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I create a Fixed thread pool using        Exectors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
I submit two such tasks that they cause dead lock for two threads of above pool. Since these two Threads will never pick any more tasks from work queue. Is Thread pool intelligent enough to identify such situation and add two more threads. 
In my opinion its NO.
But interviewer disagreed with me. He said if same dead lock happens for remaining three threads then Thread pool is useless. I will never use such API.

Comment: It is called "FixedThreadPool" for very good reason - it has as much runners as you told it to. If it tried to add two more threads, it would now have seven runners, so it would violate its contract.

Comment: To summarize: In your opinion , the thread pool isn't intelligent enough to add two more threads. Your interviewer said if the same dead lock happens for the remaining threads then the Thread pool is useless. I don't see any issue with either statement. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think both statements are true.

Comment: yes both statements are correct, but interviewer was saying it will create new thread.